# Display taxonomy parent tid of a taxonomy term reference field

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

On a node template , i  am displaying a taxonomy term ( entity ref field ).
That taxonomy term has a parent.
How can have that info on the html generated , for css purposes ?

The field.html.twig display this:

```
<div class="article__categorie-article">
              <div><a href="/taxonomy/term/27" hreflang="fr">Utilisation de Drupal</a></div>
              <div><a href="/taxonomy/term/29" hreflang="fr">Rôle</a></div>
</div>
```

I would like to have smth like

```
<div class="article__categorie-article">
              <div><a href="/taxonomy/term/27" hreflang="fr" data-parent-tid="2">Utilisation de Drupal</a></div>
              <div><a href="/taxonomy/term/29" hreflang="fr" data-parent-tid="4">Rôle</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: My suggestion for this would be to create an array to pass to the twig template. In `.theme` file, use an alter function. Create a `$variables['taxonomy'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('articles');` and then now in the twig file you can use the taxonomy variable.